# missing stop words from spacy en_core_web_lg

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp, spacy

I downloaded [en_core_web_lg](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases//tag/en_core_web_lg-2.0.0)(en_core_web_lg-2.0.0) but when I load it and used it on spacy. But it seems to miss lots of basic common stop words such as "be", "a" etc. Am I missing correct version ?

```
import nltk
n = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
"be" in n
```

O/P: True

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")
nlp.vocab["be"].is_stop
```

O/P: False

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've probably run into this bug:

https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/1574

Stop words are missing for the en_core_web_md and en_core_web_lg models, but your code will work as expected with en_core_web_sm.

Answer (score 0):

English language stop words are defined in [this](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/lang/en/stop_words.py) file and as you can see, be belongs to them.

You can import the english stop words set and then check if your word belongs to it. 
There are probably easier ways but the following code for sure achieves what you are looking for:

```
from spacy.lang.en import STOP_WORDS
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
doc = nlp("be amazing")
for token in doc:
    if (token.text in STOP_WORDS):
        print(token.text)
```